# Location Searching: Specific Address vs local businesses

Tags: ios, api, search, geolocation, full-text-search

I'm building a location app for iOS. I currently have a search bar that can be used to search for local business (e.g. pizza, gas station, bank). The search bar text is added as a parameter to a URL and fed to Yahoo Local API. I would like to use the same search bar to find specific addresses as well, but that is not a function of the API.  I'm thinking I have to either:

A) Build some function that can differentiate between a broad business search and specific location search.  Send business queries to the API and send address searches to the CLGeocoder.

B) Find a more versatile API.

C) Do something else I haven't considered yet.

I could add a separate search field and use that for address searches but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it from the same search bar.  If anyone could offer any advice or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have a hard time doing A as addresses and POIs are pretty freeform strings, especially when they are human generated strings. I would rather recommend adding some sort of switch that the user can toggle in order to search for businesses or addresses.

For B, you might want to take a look at the [Google maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), if it meets your needs. This seems pretty versatile regarding input parameters.

Comment: The Maps API is a good idea, except that you have to display a Google Map to the user according to the TOS. Just something to be aware of since I'm not sure if Gabriel is doing that or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've gone ahead and implemented a class that uses Google Maps Geocoding API.  It works pretty well so far.  I'm just trying to work out how to sort the results so I only display the closest ones to the user's location.  For example, "22 Churchill Drive" gives me results from Arkansas to Massachusetts.  I understand that geocoding is more accurate with the more information you give it, but I see no need to return results that are over 1000 miles away.

Comment: Oh by the way, Matej.  Thanks for the switch idea.  That is definitely an option if I get too hung up on this whole unified location search bar thing.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for an interesting question. It's definitely a programming design question, but almost a UX  question, too.

I think you can do it all in one field. I work for [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) where we parse and process addresses. Here's a few things I have learned from experience, related to your question:

- Don't use regular expressions to parse or determine addresses. It's too complicated. Addresses come in many different forms, like Matej said. "Freeform strings" can be anything. The temptation is to use regex, but there is a *smarter* way.
- Very few location/address APIs actually provide the value and results that you're looking for, at least according to their TOS. For example, Google, Yahoo!, and others require a map to be displayed and don't allow automated querying (e.g. no user actively initiating the request).
- Most APIs only perform address *approximation*, not address *verification*. Thus, the results you get are at best, a guess. Google is good at guessing, but results may come back that look legitimate that really aren't. I've seen this a lot and it's bitten me. Geolocation/geocoding APIs have their place, but they also have their limitations.

So, an example: a user types either a POI or an address into that text field. You're not sure which one it ism or if it's both. And if you *did* know, does the POI or address exist? I don't know of an (inexpensive) API that performs both at once -- there are enterprise-grade ones I've seen, but... probably too much bang for too many bucks. Here's an easier approach that I would try.

1. Find a CASS-Certified service to check for an address. SmartyStreets' [LiveAddress API](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api) ([different demo on homepage](http://smartystreets.com)) is one such service (inexpensive, even free for low volume usage). While the API doesn't directly parse single-line addresses, it's really easy to using **[this algorithm](http://smartystreets.com/answers/questions/318/can-i-verify-a-freeform-address-with-your-service)** (with [a working example here](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/blob/master/jQuery/slap.html)) -- it's even easier in Objective C because you don't have to mess with JSONP like you do in Javascript.
2. If LiveAddress or equivalent service (I encourage you to do some research and let me know if you have further questions -- I'll be happy to help), returns any results, the string was an address. Some CASS-Certified services, be warned, will return fake addresses or guesses also, and it's hard/impossible to distinguish between the two. LiveAddress will only return *valid* addresses. So if LiveAddress returns a result (usually the first, using the above algorithm), the string was definitely an address, or a POI followed by an address. (And yes, LiveAddress will geocode each address.)
3. If no results were returned, then it was a POI/business name. If your app adheres to Google or Yahoo's TOS, query their API because they're good at guessing and finding more generic matches on things like that.

Even another option would be to query the Maps API first and then, with the address (if any) it returns, send it through LiveAddress to make sure it exists and learn more about it.

Hope that points you in the right direction (no pun intended). Let me know if you'd like clarification on anything or have any other address-related questions.

Comment: Thanks, for the response.  Great information here.  The course I think I'm going to follow is to use a Geocoding API (Google Maps) first.  If that does not generate any results I can send the same query to a local business API (Yahoo Local or Google Places). So for instance, if a user types in "pizza" that *should* fail the geocoding search and then get passed to the business API and produce results.

Comment: Ok. That'll probably be effective. If you think to, post your results here when you've implemented it and tried it; I'm curious to see how well it works. Just bear in mind, though, that if the user types an address, you won't really be sure if the address actually exists, thus throwing off the coordinates.

Comment: There in lies the rub.  I'm really depending on the "best guess" of the API.  I just finished a test and so far it works.  I have a class for an address search and a local business search.  If the address search fails it passes the query string to the local business search.  Now I'm sure it isn't full proof.  If you search JFK airport you'll get the airport and everything that goes with it (JFK parking lot, JFK shuttle, JFK beef patties).  I'll keep futzing with it but I have a feeling I may go the switch that Matej suggested.